# Mails are not getting delivered

Tags: linux, postfix, smtp

I am facing the below error while sending the mail to yahoo and I have configured policyd on my server.

```
relay=none, delay=150, delays=0.32/0.01/150/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mta5.am0.yahoodns.net[98.136.216.26]:25: Connection timed out)
```

Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

The error message:

```
(connect to mta5.am0.yahoodns.net[98.136.216.26]:25: Connection timed out)
```

probably means that your hosting provider blocks port 25 outbound unless you ask them to open it up for you.  It may mean you have a firewall on your host machine that isn't allowing port 25 outbound.

This is usually done because so many people configure their mails servers to be open relays or misconfigure them in other ways so that they end up sending spam.  Sometimes it is because your hosting provider also have a smarthost that they want you to use and pay extra for.